# How to block assign value which is other type

Tags: typescript

Javascript easily give us flexiblity to pushing values what we wants to variable.
But how to block(throw error) it in typescript
To clarify problem maybe i give you example

```
let array: Array<string> = [];
array.push(5);
console.log(array);
```

Of course IDE notify me that 5 is not string but it still compiles and shows array with 5. How to prevent it, i mean my program should stop operation pushing 5 to array

Comment: I am not expert on Typescript, but JS is flexible, so maybe `5` is converted to string `"5"`? Why not write your own parser? To answer your question: throw error with `throw "messageOfError"`

Answer (score 0):

this is a great question! I'd first ask why you want to do this check at runtime at all (if you prevent it at compile time, and all of your code is typed with TypeScript, then you probably don't need a runtime check).

That said, it's easy to write a check like this yourself:

```
function pushChecked(array: Array<string>, value: string): void {
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    throw TypeError('value has to be a string!')
  }
  array.push(value)
}

let array: Array<string> = []
pushChecked(array, '5') // OK
pushChecked(array, 5) // Error (both at compile time, and at runtime)
```

There are plenty of libraries that help with this (what you're looking for is called a "runtime type assertion"). For example, see [is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is), [izzy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/izzy), or [@sindresorhus/is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sindresorhus/is).

Comment: Ok, so i have to write own function, just thougth ts has built-in feature for that. Anyway thank you